# pgfgantt gives error when used with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfgantt

I'm trying to include a gantt chart in my tex document using pgfgantt. When I use the package pgfplots I get the following error:

> ! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' is not part of the layer list. Please verify that you provided \pgfsetlayers and that background
>   ' is part of this list.

When I comment out the \usepackage{pgfplots} line, the gantt chart is produced. The reason I need to include it is because I use the matlab2tikz package to plot figures and that requires the pgfplots package.

A code that reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\label{section:gantt}

\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.5cm,
               y unit chart=0.5cm,
               x unit=0.22cm,
               progress=today,  
               today=24, 
               today rule/.style={Black, thick},
               vgrid={draw=none, dotted},
               hgrid, 
               link/.append style={thick},  
               title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
               title height=1,
               bar/.style={fill=OliveGreen},
               bar incomplete/.append style={fill=YellowGreen},
               progress label text={},
               bar height=0.4
                 ]{1}{84}                  

\gantttitle{Project Timeline}{84} \\
\gantttitle{2014}{6} 
\gantttitle{2015}{24} 
\gantttitle{2016}{24} 
\gantttitle{2017}{24} 
\gantttitle{2018}{6} \\
\gantttitle{Q4}{6}
\gantttitle{Q1}{6}
\gantttitle{Q2}{6}
\gantttitle{Q3}{6}
\gantttitle{Q4}{6}
\gantttitle{Q1}{6}
\gantttitle{Q2}{6}
\gantttitle{Q3}{6}
\gantttitle{Q4}{6}
\gantttitle{Q1}{6}
\gantttitle{Q2}{6}
\gantttitle{Q3}{6}
\gantttitle{Q4}{6}
\gantttitle{Q1}{6}  \\

%tasks

\ganttbar{Task 1}       {1}{8} \\ %0
\ganttbar{Task 2}       {4}{20} \\  %1


%relations 

\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}


\end{ganttchart}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on why this happens? I have tried adding

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background}
```

to the preamble, and even though that gets rid of the error, the gantt chart does not show any bars.

Link to the log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zhibboktzboutv/testgantt.log?dl=0

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. Can you should your log-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added a link to the log file...let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is most probably, because you are using v1.9 of PGFPlots. The most recent version is v1.14. Please update the package and let us know, if you then still have this error.

Comment: Stefan is right, your problem is your outdated tex system.

Comment: I'm still stuck at trying to upgrade PGFPlots. As soon as I manage, I'll let you know if this was the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is most probably solved by updating PGFPlots to a recent version.